# Swift collectionView non reusable cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collectionView with 2 sections, each section should be based off the same cell (which only contains a UIImageView). 
The only difference between the sections is the number of cells they should contain and types of images displayed.

If I set the cellforItemAtIndexPath method to use a dequeued cell (collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier) everything populates fine, if I set it to use an instance of my custom cell without dequeuing, it crashes.

cellForItemAtIndexPath method:

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        //cannot use dequedReusableCell since some cells below scroll-line should remain highlighted
        let cell = NumbersCollectionViewCell() // CAUSES CRASH
//        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(Constants.cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NumbersCollectionViewCell // WORKS FINE
        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0: cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: numberImageFiles[indexPath.row])
        case 1: cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: specialNumberImageFiles[indexPath.row])
        default: break
        }
        return cell
    }
```

NumbersCollectionViewCell definition:

```
class NumbersCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
}
```

The error that appears is: "Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" and it highlights the "case 0" row in my cellForItemAtIndexPath method.

The reason I don't want to use a dequeued cell is that I need some of the cells to be highlighted at run-time based on user selections, and if I use a dequeued cell it doesn't seem to keep the ones below the scroll-line highlighted.

Comment: turns out my issue had nothing to do with dequeuing cells or not...it was all in the didSelect and didDeselectCellAtIndexPath methods...but had my issue been related to dequeuing cells the answer below would have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have both a `.swift` and a `.xib` file for your cell, you need to instantiate your `NumbersCollectionViewCell` like this:
E.g.

```
let numbersCollectionViewCell = UINib(nibName: "NumbersCollectionViewCell", bundle: bundle).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as! NumbersCollectionViewCell
```

Otherwise, your `IBOutlet`s will not be connected.

Comment: So I didn't have an .xib initially, but I deleted my NumbersCollectionViewCell.swift file and re-created it with an .xib this time. The problem is that when I enter the code you suggested, Xcode provides a warning on that line stating "Cast from '[AnyObject]!' to unrelated type 'NumbersCollectionViewCell' always fails" when I then run the app on the simulator, it crashes highlighting that line but providing no messages in the console

Answer (score 0):

```
 override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
     guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(identifier: "NumbersCollectionViewCell">, forIndexPath: NSIndexPath>) as? NumbersCollectionViewCell else {
         print("failed to get cell")
         return UICollectionViewCell()
         }
     switch indexPath.section {
         case 0: cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: numberImageFiles[indexPath.row])
         case 1: cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: specialNumberImageFiles[indexPath.row])
         default: break
         }
   return cell
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately using the proposed code it's still de-queuing cells which means cells below the scroll-line don't appear as shaded. So if I have some cells that get shaded at run time, then the user scrolls down and back up, the cells that were shaded are now no longer shaded since the cells have been dequeued and re-created.